# How is a lubridate date object converted when storing a dataframe into a SQLite database in R?

Tags: r, sqlite, date, lubridate

Suppose you are storing a dataframe that contains dates in a sqlite database using the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(d = lubridate::as_date(1:30))
mydb <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "database.db")
DBI::dbWriteTable(mydb, "mytable", df)
DBI::dbDisconnect(mydb)
```

my understanding is that a conversion such as

```
as.numeric(df$d)
```

is performed before saving the data into the sqlite database. Is this correct? Why is the numeric conversion instead of the string conversion preferred?

Answer (score 1):

Briefly:

1. There is no such thing as `lubridate date object`. There is a base R type `Date` you can create, _inter alias, with `as.Date()`.  If you feel you must use another package so be it.
2. The `Date` type is stored *internally* as a (floating point) number of (fractional) days since a start date (of 1970-01-01).  So storing as a number is the most efficient way.
3. Databases sometimes do, or do not, have native date types. MySQL didn't for many years; I can't recall where RSQLite is.  It does not matter because ...
4. Database *access packages* need converters from Date and Datetime *along with native support* in the database.
5. We built this into RPostgreSQL a decade ago as PostgreSQL has it natively.
6. If you want *textual* representation but either one (or both) of the interface or database layer cannot do Date types, then call `format()` first and store the character string.  Every database knows how to do that.  But you just lost the type information...